# Column 'QM_Analysis.DefectLocation' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, procedure

i'm trying to create this stored procedure, the problem is that when I put count() on the SELECT list it returns the error: "Column 'QM_Analysis.DefectLocation' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I've already tried many things but still returns the same error.

Someone have some tip ?

Thanks in advance

```
USE [JEMS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[up_RE_Rpt_Defect_new]    Script Date: 01/08/2013 11:35:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

/*
[up_RE_Rpt_Defect_new] 
@Factory ="",
@Customer_ID ='25',
@Manuf_Area = null,--'136',
@Route =null,--361,
@Step = null,--1848,
@DateFrom ='2012-10-25  00:00:00.000',
@DateTo ='2012-10-25  09:00:00.000',
@hrFrom = '06:00',
@hrTo = '14:00',
@language = 9,
@family = null
*/

ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_RE_Rpt_Defect_new]

-- Plant> Customer> Manufacturing Area> Route> Step> DateFrom> DateTo> TopNvalues;

@Factory as varchar(20)= null,
@Customer_ID as varchar(50)= null,
@Manuf_Area as varchar(50)= null,
@Route as varchar(400) = null,
@Step as varchar(400)= null,
@DateFrom as datetime= null,
@DateTo datetime = null,
@hrFrom as varchar(5) = null,
@hrTo as varchar(5) = null,
@TopN as varchar(20)= null,
@language as int = null,
@family as varchar(5) = null

AS

--declare @Factory as varchar(20),
--@Customer_ID as varchar(20),
--@Manuf_Area as varchar(20),
--@Route as varchar(50) ,
--@Step as varchar(20),
--@DateFrom as smalldatetime,
--@DateFrom2 as smalldatetime,
--@hrFrom as varchar(5) ,
--@hrTo as varchar(5) ,
--@DateTo smalldatetime ,
--@DateTo2 varchar(20) ,
--@TopN as varchar(20)

--SET @Customer_ID = 25
--SET @Factory = 7
--SET @Manuf_Area = 136
--SET @DateFrom  = '2012-10-23  05:00:00.000' -- CONVERT(varchar(12),@DateFrom,103)
--SET @DateTo  = '2012-10-23  09:00:00.000'
--SET @hrFrom = '08:00'
--SET @hrTo = '09:00'
--SET @language = 9

IF @Factory = ""
    BEGIN SET @Factory = null 
END

IF @Manuf_Area= ""
    BEGIN SET @Manuf_Area = null 
END

IF @Route = ""
    BEGIN SET @Route = null 
END

IF @Step = ""
    BEGIN SET @Step = null 
END

IF @family  = ""
    BEGIN SET @family = null 
END

DECLARE @Select as varchar(7000)
DECLARE @Where as varchar(7000)

SET @Select = 
'SELECT TOP 10 
    COUNT(qman.DefectLocation) as cont,
    qman.DefectLocation
FROM QM_Analysis qman WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN QM_TestData td           WITH(NOLOCK) on qman.Wip_ID = td.Wip_ID AND qman.Process_ID = td.Process_ID
    INNER JOIN QM_Fixture qf            WITH(NOLOCK) on td.Fixture_ID = qf.Fixture_ID
    INNER JOIN QM_Defects def           WITH(NOLOCK) on qman.Defect_ID = def.Defect_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_Text defText          WITH(NOLOCK) on def.Defect = defText.Text_ID
    INNER JOIN CT_FeederTrayTrack ftt   WITH(NOLOCK) on qman.FeederTrayTrack_ID = ftt.FeederTrayTrack_ID
    INNER JOIN QM_DataAnalysis da       WITH(NOLOCK) on qman.Analysis_ID = da.Analysis_ID 
    INNER JOIN CR_Text ansText1         WITH(NOLOCK) on ansText1.Language_ID = 0 AND da.AnalysisStatus = ansText1.Translation
    INNER JOIN QM_AnalysisStatus ans    WITH(NOLOCK) on ansText1.Text_ID = ans.AnalysisStatus
    INNER JOIN CR_Text ansText2         WITH(NOLOCK) on ans.Descr = ansText2.Text_ID AND ansText2.Language_ID = defText.Language_ID
    INNER JOIN WP_Wip w                 WITH(NOLOCK) on td.Wip_ID = w.Wip_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_Materials m           WITH(NOLOCK) on qman.Material_ID = m.Material_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_Assemblies a          WITH(NOLOCK) on td.Assembly_ID = a.Assembly_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_Families fam          WITH(NOLOCK) on a.Family_ID = fam.Family_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_Text famText          WITH(NOLOCK) on fam.Family = famText.Text_ID AND famText.Language_ID = defText.Language_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_Customers c           WITH(NOLOCK) on a.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_Text cText            WITH(NOLOCK) on c.Customer = cText.Text_ID AND cText.Language_ID = defText.Language_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_Text dText            WITH(NOLOCK) on c.Division = dText.Text_ID AND dText.Language_ID = defText.Language_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_Text eText            WITH(NOLOCK) on qf.Fixture = eText.Text_ID AND eText.Language_ID = defText.Language_ID
    LEFT JOIN CT_EquipmentSETup es      WITH(NOLOCK) on qman.EquipmentOrRouteStep_ID = es.EquipmentSETup_ID AND qman.IsEquipment = 1
    LEFT JOIN CR_Equipment_V e          WITH(NOLOCK) on es.Equipment_ID = e.Equipment_ID
    LEFT JOIN CR_FMRS4_V fmrs1          WITH(NOLOCK) on es.RouteStep_ID = fmrs1.RouteStep_ID AND fmrs1.Language_ID = defText.Language_ID
    LEFT JOIN CT_RouteStepSETup rss     WITH(NOLOCK) on qman.EquipmentOrRouteStep_ID = rss.RouteStepSETup_ID AND qman.IsEquipment = 0
    LEFT JOIN CR_FMRS4_V fmrs2          WITH(NOLOCK) on rss.RouteStep_ID = fmrs2.RouteStep_ID AND fmrs2.Language_ID = defText.Language_ID
    LEFT JOIN CR_Equipment_V e3         WITH(NOLOCK) on td.Equipment_ID = e3.Equipment_ID
    INNER JOIN CR_FMRS4_V fmrs3         WITH(NOLOCK) on td.RouteStep_ID = fmrs3.RouteStep_ID AND fmrs3.Language_ID = defText.Language_ID 
    --- separeted
    JOIN CR_FMRS4_V fmrs4               WITH(NOLOCK) on qman.RouteStep_ID = fmrs4.RouteStep_ID AND fmrs4.Language_ID = defText.Language_ID
    INNER JOIN SC_Users ut              WITH(NOLOCK) on td.OperatorID_ID = ut.UserID_ID
    INNER JOIN SC_Users ua              WITH(NOLOCK) on qman.AnalysisBy_ID = ua.UserID_ID
    LEFT JOIN QM_DataRec dr             WITH(NOLOCK) on da.Data_ID = dr.Data_ID AND da.Wip_ID = dr.Wip_ID AND da.Process_ID = dr.Process_ID'

SET @Where = ' WHERE ' +        
'C.Customer_ID = ' + CONVERT(varchar(8),@Customer_ID ) +
' AND defText.Language_ID = ' + CAST(@language as varchar(3)) +
' AND da.AssociatedDefectFlag = '+'''F''' + -- AND a.Assembly_ID = '10587' --P266-8446100
' AND a.Active=1 AND def.defect_ID = 126 ' 

IF @Factory IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
    SET @Where = @Where + ' AND (fmrs2.Factory_ID = ' + CAST(@Factory as varchar(10)) + ' or fmrs4.Factory_ID = ' + 
    CAST(@Factory as varchar(2)) + ')'  -- AND fmrs3.Factory_ID = @Factory AND fmrs4.Factory_ID = @Factory 
END

IF @Manuf_Area IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    SET @Where = @Where + ' AND fmrs3.FactoryMA_ID = ' + CAST(@Manuf_Area as varchar(5)) 
END

IF @family IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    SET @Where = @Where + ' AND fam.Family_ID = ' + CAST(@family AS VARCHAR(5)) 
END

IF @Route IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    SET @Where = @Where + ' AND fmrs3.FactoryMARoute_ID in(' + CAST(@Route as varchar(10)) + ') ' +
                          ' AND fmrs4.FactoryMARoute_ID in(' + CAST(@Route as varchar(10)) + ') '
END

IF @Step IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    SET @Where = @Where + ' AND (fmrs3.RouteStep_ID in(' + CAST(@Step as varchar(50)) + ') or fmrs4.RouteStep_ID in (' + 
    CAST(@Step as varchar(50)) + '))'
END

SET @Where = @Where + 'AND CONVERT(varchar(5),td.LastUpdated,114) between ''' + @hrFrom + ''' AND ''' + @hrTo + '''' + 
'AND td.LastUpdated between ''' + CONVERT(varchar(12),@DateFrom,111) + ' ' + @hrFrom + ':00.000' + ''' AND ''' + 
CONVERT(varchar(12),@DateTo,111) + ' ' + @hrTo + ':00.000'''

SET @Where = @Where + 'GROUP BY qman.DefectLocation ORDER BY count(qman.DefectLocation) DESC'

PRINT (@select + @Where)
EXEC  (@select + @Where)
```

Comment: at first glance it seems like your "GROUP BY" is right after the string ':00.000''' without any spaces inbetween (':00.000'GROUP BY) Can you take a look at that and, if still doesn't work, please paste your complete formatted query

Comment: Can you post the result of the `PRINT(@select + @Where)`?

Comment: You say you're on SQL Server 2008. If you are, and the caution doesn't rule it out, it's probably worth reading [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). You should be able to build this as a single static query and specify `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` and not have to do all of this string concatenation.